# Trying to make an RPM for PCRE-8.31

Tags: dependencies, centos, rpm, updates, yum

I am trying to make an RPM to install PCRE-8.31 on a CentOS 6.3 machine. You can see my spec file. Despite matching all the requirements (to the best of my understanding) I am getting the following errors when tring to install the package. I am placing a symbolic link to libpcre.so.0 in the right place, so what am I doing wrong?

#### pcre.spec

```
Name:           pcre
Version:        8.31
Release:        1%{?dist}
Summary:        Perl Compatible Expressions Library

Group:          Libraries
License:        BSD
URL:            http://wwww.pcre.org/
Source0:        ftp://ftp.csx.cam.ac.uk/pub/software/programming/pcre/pcre-8.31.tar.bz2
BuildRoot:      %{_tmppath}/%{name}-%{version}-%{release}-root-%(%{ __id_u} -n)

BuildRequires: readline-devel
BuildRequires: autoconf, automake, libtool

%description
Perl-compatible regular expression library.
PCRE has its own native API, but a set of "wrapper" functions that are based on
the POSIX API are also supplied in the library libpcreposix. Note that this
just provides a POSIX calling interface to PCRE: the regular expressions
themselves still follow Perl syntax and semantics. The header file
for the POSIX-style functions is called pcreposix.h.




%package devel
Summary: Development files for %{name}
Group: Development/Libraries
Requires: %{name} = %{version}-%{release}

%description devel
Development files (Headers, libraries for static linking, etc) for %{name}.




%prep
%setup -q



%build
%configure \
        --prefix=/usr \
        --build=x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu \
        --docdir=/usr/share/doc/pcre-8.31 \
        --enable-jit \
            --enable-pcre8 \
        --enable-pcre16 \
        --enable-pcregrep-libz \
        --enable-pcregrep-libbz2 \
        --enable-pcretest-libreadline \
        --enable-rebuild-chartables \
        --enable-unicode-properties \
        --enable-utf \
            --disable-static \
            CC="gcc -m64" \
            CXX="g++ -m64"
make %{?_smp_mflags}



%install
rm -Rf %{buildroot}

make install DESTDIR=$RPM_BUILD_ROOT

mkdir -p %{buildroot}/%{_lib}
mv %{buildroot}%{_libdir}/libpcre.so.* %{buildroot}/%{_lib}/
pushd %{buildroot}/%{_lib}
ln -fs libpcre.so.1.0.1 libpcre.so.0
popd

rm -f %{buildroot}%{_libdir}/*.la


%check
make check

%post -p /sbin/ldconfig

%postun -p /sbin/ldconfig

%clean
rm -Rf %{buildroot}

%files
%defattr(-,root,root)
/%{_lib}/*.so.*
%{_libdir}/*.so.*
%{_mandir}/man1/*
%{_bindir}/pcregrep
%{_bindir}/pcretest
%doc LICENCE AUTHORS

%files devel
%defattr(-,root,root)
%{_libdir}/*.so
%{_libdir}/pkgconfig/*
%{_includedir}/*.h
%{_mandir}/man3/*
%{_bindir}/pcre-config
%{_prefix}/share/doc/%{name}-%{version}/*

%changelog
```

#### Installation

```
# yum install pcre-8.31-1.el6.x86_64.rpm
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, refresh-packagekit, security
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
Setting up Install Process
Examining pcre-8.31-1.el6.x86_64.rpm: pcre-8.31-1.el6.x86_64
Marking pcre-8.31-1.el6.x86_64.rpm as an update to pcre-7.8-4.el6.x86_64
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package pcre.x86_64 0:7.8-4.el6 will be updated
--> Processing Dependency: libpcre.so.0()(64bit) for package: 1:libguestfs-1.16.19-1.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libpcre.so.0()(64bit) for package: 6:kdelibs-4.3.4-14.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libpcre.so.0()(64bit) for package: httpd-2.2.15-15.el6.centos.1.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libpcre.so.0()(64bit) for package: sssd-1.8.0-32.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libpcre.so.0()(64bit) for package: grep-2.6.3-3.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libpcre.so.0()(64bit) for package: kdelibs3-3.5.10-24.el6_1.1.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libpcre.so.0()(64bit) for package: gnote-0.6.3-3.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libpcre.so.0()(64bit) for package: less-436-10.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libpcre.so.0()(64bit) for package: httpd-tools-2.2.15-15.el6.centos.1.x86_64
---> Package pcre.x86_64 0:8.31-1.el6 will be an update
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: 1:libguestfs-1.16.19-1.el6.x86_64 (@c6-media)
           Requires: libpcre.so.0()(64bit)
           Removing: pcre-7.8-4.el6.x86_64 (@anaconda-CentOS-201207061011.x86_64/6.3)
               libpcre.so.0()(64bit)
           Updated By: pcre-8.31-1.el6.x86_64 (/pcre-8.31-1.el6.x86_64)
               Not found
Error: Package: httpd-2.2.15-15.el6.centos.1.x86_64 (@anaconda-CentOS-201207061011.x86_64/6.3)
           Requires: libpcre.so.0()(64bit)
           Removing: pcre-7.8-4.el6.x86_64 (@anaconda-CentOS-201207061011.x86_64/6.3)
               libpcre.so.0()(64bit)
           Updated By: pcre-8.31-1.el6.x86_64 (/pcre-8.31-1.el6.x86_64)
               Not found
Error: Package: gnote-0.6.3-3.el6.x86_64 (@anaconda-CentOS-201207061011.x86_64/6.3)
           Requires: libpcre.so.0()(64bit)
           Removing: pcre-7.8-4.el6.x86_64 (@anaconda-CentOS-201207061011.x86_64/6.3)
               libpcre.so.0()(64bit)
           Updated By: pcre-8.31-1.el6.x86_64 (/pcre-8.31-1.el6.x86_64)
               Not found
Error: Package: 6:kdelibs-4.3.4-14.el6.x86_64 (@c6-media)
           Requires: libpcre.so.0()(64bit)
           Removing: pcre-7.8-4.el6.x86_64 (@anaconda-CentOS-201207061011.x86_64/6.3)
               libpcre.so.0()(64bit)
           Updated By: pcre-8.31-1.el6.x86_64 (/pcre-8.31-1.el6.x86_64)
               Not found
Error: Package: grep-2.6.3-3.el6.x86_64 (@anaconda-CentOS-201207061011.x86_64/6.3)
           Requires: libpcre.so.0()(64bit)
           Removing: pcre-7.8-4.el6.x86_64 (@anaconda-CentOS-201207061011.x86_64/6.3)
               libpcre.so.0()(64bit)
           Updated By: pcre-8.31-1.el6.x86_64 (/pcre-8.31-1.el6.x86_64)
               Not found
Error: Package: kdelibs3-3.5.10-24.el6_1.1.x86_64 (@c6-media)
           Requires: libpcre.so.0()(64bit)
           Removing: pcre-7.8-4.el6.x86_64 (@anaconda-CentOS-201207061011.x86_64/6.3)
               libpcre.so.0()(64bit)
           Updated By: pcre-8.31-1.el6.x86_64 (/pcre-8.31-1.el6.x86_64)
               Not found
Error: Package: httpd-tools-2.2.15-15.el6.centos.1.x86_64 (@anaconda-CentOS-201207061011.x86_64/6.3)
           Requires: libpcre.so.0()(64bit)
           Removing: pcre-7.8-4.el6.x86_64 (@anaconda-CentOS-201207061011.x86_64/6.3)
               libpcre.so.0()(64bit)
           Updated By: pcre-8.31-1.el6.x86_64 (/pcre-8.31-1.el6.x86_64)
               Not found
Error: Package: sssd-1.8.0-32.el6.x86_64 (@anaconda-CentOS-201207061011.x86_64/6.3)
           Requires: libpcre.so.0()(64bit)
           Removing: pcre-7.8-4.el6.x86_64 (@anaconda-CentOS-201207061011.x86_64/6.3)
               libpcre.so.0()(64bit)
           Updated By: pcre-8.31-1.el6.x86_64 (/pcre-8.31-1.el6.x86_64)
               Not found
Error: Package: less-436-10.el6.x86_64 (@anaconda-CentOS-201207061011.x86_64/6.3)
           Requires: libpcre.so.0()(64bit)
           Removing: pcre-7.8-4.el6.x86_64 (@anaconda-CentOS-201207061011.x86_64/6.3)
               libpcre.so.0()(64bit)
           Updated By: pcre-8.31-1.el6.x86_64 (/pcre-8.31-1.el6.x86_64)
               Not found
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Comment: You might want to paste the output of rpmbuild, especially at the end when it is determining requires/provides.

Answer (score 1):

The version 7.x of PCRE that is provided by CentOS 6 contains the shared library whose SO version is 0(libpcre.so.0).
And it is different from that of PCRE 8.1 package you have tried to build, libpcre.so.1.

Even if you force to install the package, it is highly possible that the softwares that are shown as dependencies won't work well.

If the customized PCRE is supposed to be used restrictively for a specific purpose, you need to change its package name
not to conflict the original name and install it in a different directory than the original.

```
%define _prefix /usr/local
```